# Whats the best way in kotlin for an null object's toString() method to return an empty string instead of "null"

Tags: string, kotlin, null, nullable

According to the official kotlin documentation, the toString() call of a null object returns "null" [toString()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html)

I want, that toString() should return an empty string ("") instead. I implemented it with an extension function.

```
fun Any?.toEmptyStringIfNull() :String {
if (this == null) {
    return ""
} else {
    return toString()
}
```

I am wondering if this could be achieved simpler/easier/cleaner and without calling the extension function everytime.

Answer (score 58):

How about:

```
nullable?.toString() ?: ""
```

or as [Alexander Udalov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288456/alexander-udalov) suggested:

```
nullable?.toString().orEmpty()
```

Which one can wrap in an extension method:

```
fun Any?.toStringOrEmpty() = this?.toString() ?: ""
```

Comment: Or a slightly more readable version: `nullable?.toString().orEmpty()`

Comment: The implementation could probably be `"${this ?: ""}"`, if you don't care about less performance

Answer (score 18):

you can directly use `nullable.orEmpty()`.

Reference:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/or-empty.html

**Edit:** 
*Answer provided is incomplete* - does only apply for `String?` and not `Any?` as pointed out in comment below.

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: `orEmpty` takes a `String` object, and the question is about converting `Any?` to `String`.

Comment: @javaxian, thanks for pointing out. You are indeed correct.
Will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
nullable?.let {it.toString()}
```

If "nullable" is null it won't go further. As a variant. The only problem is that there will be a warning "redundant 'let' call could be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I propose an extension function `stringify`, the name of which I borrowed from JavaScript's `JSON.stringify()`.

```kotlin
fun <T> T?.stringify(toString: (T) -> String = { it.toString() }): String =
    if (this == null) "" else toString(this)
```

This covers the simple case and cases where you want to further process the string:

```kotlin
fun simplyConcatenate(s: String, postfix: String?): String = 
    s + postfix.stringify()

fun getFullTitle(title: String, disambiguation: String?): String = 
    title + disambiguation.stringify { " ($it)" }

fun demo() {
    println(simplyConcatenate("a", null)) // "a"
    println(simplyConcatenate("a", "b")) // "ab"
    println(getFullTitle("a", null)) // "a"
    println(getFullTitle("a", "b")) // "a (b)"
}
```

Edit: Now available in [kotlin-lib](https://github.com/marco-eckstein/kotlin-lib).

Answer (score 0):

The above answer not work for variable that is not original as String?
because the toString() will directly transform a Any? to String (not to String?)
if you write something like xxx.toString() ?: "" or xxx.toString().orEmpty() the IDE will tell you the right path will never be reach.

The solution is use "let" or "run". Depend on do you need to access outer scope class’ fun.

```
    Any? let { it.toString() } ?: ""
    Any? run { toString() } ?: ""
```

For example a fun we want a file name string from a nullable Path, or even a non-null path, its getFileName() may return null. And we want a empty string in that case instead of a "null" string.

```
    fun fileName(path: Path?): String = path?.fileName?.run { toString() } ?: ""

    fun removeExtension(path: Path?): String = path?.fileName?.let { removeExtension(it.toString()) } ?: ""
    fun removeExtension(fileName: String): String = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(fileName)
```